# UITabBarController and UITabbar with background images for UIBarButon

Tags: iphone, image, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Hello, please forgive me for asking very common question, I created uitoolbarcontroller in app delegate, and assign title for tabbar in view did load of view controller.

Code is here:

```
   [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"Exercise Dict."];
```

Please tell me how to set the image as background insted of title.

I added this in same method for background image:

```
 [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Beginner-1"]];
```

But its giving an error='NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarItem setBackgroundImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa25e9a0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"];
```

Comment: i have adde ur method in view did load in my project, but nothing chage

Comment: self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your-png-image.png"]; add this

Comment: how to set size for the image for each tab or max size

Comment: i have three tab bar item ,as i put ur recommanded image 30*30, its comin 6 times up and downs in one tab, not one image for one tab, please help

Comment: make image dimension of 30*30 & then set for one tab like your code as you set image in background.

Comment: If you confuse then ask a new question with proper problem that you have faced.

Comment: its settin to all tab , please how to select tab for setting up images

Comment: Vishal u have solved almost all, but need little more help please

Comment: ok you want to set different images to all of your three tab?ok right?

Comment: how to select tab for different image please

Comment: [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"234.jpg"]]; why thios method not workin

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27914/discussion-between-user2256034-and-vishal)